# Sqoop hive importing incorrect data

Tags: postgresql, import, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import data from PGSQL and load into Hive using sqoop
Query used:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://${HOST}:${PORT}/${INST} --username=${USER} --password=$PASS} --delete-target-dir --target-dir /TC/Customer --query "Select event_id, customer_id,subscriber_id, PROCESSING_STATUS from Customer WHERE \$CONDITIONS and PROCESSING_STATUS='RD'" --where " 1=1 "  -m 1 --fields-terminated-by "," --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table Customer
```

The counts will match after sqoop command is successful, but there are few records in destination which is not at all present in source.
i tried split-by on pkey but same error

Comment: can you pls post - what kind of extra rows? can you see if your data has new lines etc. in it ?

Comment: @KoushikRoy, example: select * from customer where event_id =15391088790000000 ; ---> this is giving a row in HIVE but i don't have any data with this record in my Postgres

Comment: have you compared hive and postgres table structure, column sequence, and datatype? then may be keep only 100 rows in postgres and then try to sqoop in. try to determine which point it fails. may be its mapping different column.

Comment: M trying to create a new table so it handles the datatype internally. i even tried "--create_hive_table" still it gives me random rows after import